# Executing commands one with a loop with cmd

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a batch file that both executes a command once, and do a loop at the same time. When the loop occurs again, the command won't be executed anymore. Here is the code for the loop:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"

FOR /L %%n in (1,1,10) DO (
    call :spinner
    ping localhost -n 2 > nul
)
exit /b

:spinner
set /a "spinner=(spinner + 1) %% 4"
set "spinChars=\|/-"
<nul set /p ".=Rebuilding, please wait... !spinChars:~%spinner%,1!!CR!"
exit /b
```

However there's a problem: The loop will execute and only executes when the command is done. And there are no timeouts for the loop, so basically, it will do the loop forever, until I press Ctrl + C. 
Can anyone help me with this? And if you can, please make the code above better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to execute the command only once, but you want to use a loop, why use the loop? What's getting looped?

Comment: For it to be cool, I guess, you can choose to do it or not, it will be fine. And the loop is a loading loop

Comment: which of them is the command, you want to run once?

Comment: Any command, as long as it runs the same time as the loop, and most importantly, it must still continue while the loop is still running.

Comment: So you want something like `for /L %%A in (1,1,10) do if "%%A"=="1" echo This will loop 9 more times but never echo again`?

Comment: Yeah, something like it

Comment: `START` the command, without the `/WAIT` option just before the `:loop`.

Comment: Can we do it after the loop?

Comment: You can do it During the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable with a true value when the command is executed in the first instance, and Conditional testing in that variable prior to executing said command

```
If not "!EXC!" == "" (Echo First Run) Else (Set "EXC=True")
```

Example uses delayed expansion as it is usable both in For Loops and Label Loops.

If you want to Break the Loop, Use the conditional testing to Goto :Label

## Update

Now that you've provided more detail in your question, I believe something like this is what you're going for.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" ^> nul') do set "CR=%%a"
set "spinChars=\|/-"
   for /f "delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H# &echo on &for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
      set "BS=%%a"
      set "BS=!BS:~0,1!"
   )

<nul set/p=Rebuilding, please wait... 
FOR /L %%. in () DO (
REM insert conditional testing to break loop Here
    set /a "spinner=(spinner + 1) %% 4"
    For %%/ in (!Spinner!) Do <nul set /p=%BS%!spinChars:~%%/,1!
)
exit /b

:End_Loop
Echo You have Exited the process
Pause
Exit /B
```

The Definition of the Backspace Character comes from this [post](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2124)

Whatever process your waiting for in the loading loop you will need some method to test for it's completion. Seeing as you've not detailed, I'll suggest some options:

- Existance of a file
- Value of a Variable
- result of testing against tasklist to see if a task is still active.

If you provide more detail regarding the command / process you are waiting on, a better answer regarding the conditional testing can be offered.

An example method that runs a subroutine as a seperate instance in the same window, and uses Signal Files to communicate to the main Loop when command execution has completed:

```
::: ** Batch Multithreading example by T3RRY ** :::
    @Echo Off & CD "%~dp0"                      :::
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

::: - Define any Variables to be used by both Environments
    Set "spinChars=\|/-"
::: - Test if Thread Two is to be executed
    If /I "%~1" == "Thread2" Goto :Thread2
::: - Localise Thread Ones Environment
    Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
::: - Ensure previous Signal files removed in case program exited incorrectly
    Del /Q /F "%TEMP%\CMDrun.log"
    Del /Q /F "%TEMP%\CMDend.log"
    CLS
::: - Define Backspace Character for Animation
    For /F "delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H# &echo on &for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
      Set "BS=%%a"
      Set "BS=!BS:~0,1!"
    )

    <Nul Set/P=Processing, please wait. 
:Loop
::: - Launch Thread Two in Same window if Not already Running
::: - Conditional tests on signal files redirect errors to Standard error to prevent erroneous output
::: - when testing occurs at the same time the file is being written to.
    (IF Not Exist "%TEMP%\CMDrun.log" Start /B "" "%~F0" Thread2) 2>Nul
::: - Animation To indicate commands in thread one are running. A Loop is used in this example.
    Set /A "spinner=(spinner + 1) %% 4"
    For %%S in (!Spinner!) Do <Nul Set /P=%BS%!spinChars:~%%S,1!
::: - Exit Thread One once Thread Two has Completed
    (IF Exist "%TEMP%\CMDend.log" Goto :End_Loop) 2>Nul
Goto :Loop

:End_Loop
::: - Clean up Signal Files
    Echo.
    Del /Q /F "%TEMP%\CMDrun.log"
    Del /Q /F "%TEMP%\CMDend.log"
    Echo Process Complete
    Pause
::: - Demonstrate stability of multithreading through repetition
    Start "" "%~F0"
Exit

:Thread2
::: Localise Thread Two's Environment
    Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    >"%TEMP%\CMDrun.log" (Echo running)
::: - Title update to demonstrate commands executed in thread two are running
    For /L %%# In (1,1,10000) Do (
        Set /a "spinner=(spinner + 1) %% 4"
        For %%S in (!Spinner!) Do TITLE !spinChars:~%%S,1! Output %%#
    )
    >"%TEMP%\CMDend.log" (Echo finished)
::: - Hard exit of Thread Two used to prevent script overflow.
EXIT
```

Comment: That idea works well, but the code automatically moves the cursor to the beginning, so if I execute the command in the first `for /l` loop, it will overwrite the phase `rebuilding`, and it doesn't move the cursor to the first line afterwards.

Comment: Your initial post lacked that detail. My answer has been updated accordingly.

Comment: One other pointer, It's not necessary to call upon a subroutine to update the value of the spinner. Loops within Loops can be used to expand variables from the delayed form

Comment: I use oscdimg to create an ISO file while the loop runs. So how exactly do you prove that the iso file is completed?

Comment: As mentioned in the suggestions, where processes are concerned, use tasklist to test if the process has stopped running

Comment: Another option may be to use start / wait for oscdimg in the second thread, as the primary loop will continue to run

Comment: Looks like the tasklist option isn't possible, since I run oscdimg on cmd. And I am not too good at batch, so what exactly does the second thread do, and why use the wait option?

Comment: The second thread executes that portion of the program Run as a seperate instance within the same window, using `Start /B`. This means the main body of the script continues to execute at the same time the script in the second thread is executing. `Start /wait` holds the execution of the second thread until the process started has finished executing. In the example I provided, signal files are created in the Second thread to indicate the start and end of it's execution in a way the intial thread can detect and interact with.

Comment: By using Start /Wait, you allow the process to complete before creating the signal file that indicates thread two's execution has completed in order to break out of the animation loop in thread one.

Comment: A slightly more complex  example can bee seen  [here](https://pastebin.com/yfXw5u73) that leverages this multithreading to rapidly build and display Full screen animations in a smooth manner

Comment: So, it's like, we add that oscdimg command to thread two, right? But where can i add that command? Also I want the thread one to stop working as soon as the second thread is done. Can we do that?

Comment: Have you not read or run the code? It is written to perform the animation loop in thread 1, the main Batch File. At the start of the animation, It initaites Thread two, Only if the CMDrun file does not exist - Which is the first thing created in thread 2. Thread 1 continues to execute it's loop until thread 2 creates the CMDend file to trigger the End of thread ones loop.

Comment: I suggest you try to actually test and understand whats happening in the code. I made sure to detail the purpose and effect of the scripts components to make this easy for you. My purpose isn't to write your program for you, it's to offer you tools and understanding to achieve your goals.

Comment: When I use `start /wait` with commands ( or batch files), they need to be closed manually. So if I use `start /wait` on oscdimg, will it be its own process, or is it cmd?